# Difference between two dates always give zero Days using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Hi I am trying to get the difference between two dates but I keep on getting 0 as the answer anyone knows why please help. My code is like this

```
  var d1 = "2015-04-30";
  var d2 = "2015-04-14";
  var startDay = new Date(d1);
  var endDay = new Date(d2);
  var millisecondsPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

  var millisBetween = startDay.getTime() - endDay.getTime();
  var days = millisBetween / millisecondsPerDay;


//If I use df1 and df2 I am getting 0
  var jsondate1 = new Date(getData.startDate).toISOString();
                var jsondate2 = new Date(getData.startDate).toISOString();

                var date = new Date(jsondate1);
                var dates = new Date(jsondate2);

   var df1 = date.getFullYear()  + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1)   + '-'
 +date.getDate() ;
 var df2 = dates.getFullYear()   + '-' +(dates.getMonth()+1) 
   + '-' +dates.getDate() ;


 //If I am using the below two lines the answer is 16 but if I am using the above d1 and d2 the answer is zero 
 var d1 = "2015-4-30";// the date here is made up by console.debug(df1 )
 var d2 = "2015-4-14"; // the date here is made up by console.debug(df2 )
```

I don't know where am I doing wrong

Comment: no i getting 0 as my answer i don't know y

Comment: days = 16. Where are you getting 0? Can you show us how you're looking at your result?

Comment: console.debug(days) = 0

Comment: Confirming `16` for `days` variable.

Comment: this works well, days is 16

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: working http://jsfiddle.net/ankit2038/jm6szoc6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work as is but you can try subtracting the dates without calling getTime():

```
var d1 = "2015-04-30";
var d2 = "2015-04-14";
var startDay = new Date(d1);
var endDay = new Date(d2);
var millisecondsPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

var millisBetween = startDay - endDay;
var days = millisBetween / millisecondsPerDay;
alert(days);
```

**After question update:**

Both jsondate1 & jsondate2 are being created using the same date (getData.startDate), hence the difference is 0:

```
var jsondate1 = new Date(getData.startDate).toISOString();
var jsondate2 = new Date(getData.startDate).toISOString();
```

Comment: This does not make sense if I am using  d1 and d2 by assigning I am getting the correct answer but if I am getting them somewhere i am getting 0

Comment: I'm not sure how you're receiving your dates? As strings? Are they in a format that can be parsed correctly by the Date() constructor?

Comment: the console.debug(df1)=  2015-04-30 and  console.debug(df2) = 2015-04-14

Comment: I'd need to see how df1 and df2 are being supplied to you. Can you supply some of the code a little further up the chain? Is it worth noting that df1 is not the same variable as d1?

Comment: @ReginwaldtLed Both jsondate1 & jsondate2 are being created using the same date (getData.startDate), hence the difference is 0.

Comment: thanks silly mistake lazy programming copy and paste. :D

Answer (score 3):

**See the snippet - It shows 16.**

```js
   var d1 = "2015-04-30";
                  var d2 = "2015-04-14";
                  var startDay = new Date(d1);
                  var endDay = new Date(d2);
                  var millisecondsPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

                  var millisBetween = startDay.getTime() - endDay.getTime();
                  var days = millisBetween / millisecondsPerDay;
alert(days);
```

I think you should **check your code at your end** , because it's working as you want but some code syntax mistake will be there in your code. (may be)

Comment: to add on my question  
 console.debug(df1)= 2015-04-30 and console.debug(df2) = 2015-04-14

Answer (score 0):

If you want date difference only. Then easiest way to do is.

```
var d1 = "2015-04-30";
var d2 = "2015-04-14";
Math.floor(( Date.parse(d1) - Date.parse(d2) ) / 86400000);
```